# Coming back from Android Market does not show app again

Tags: android, android-intent

I am starting market intent to go my app. It starts well and also showing my app. But problem with this is when pressing back, it is not coming to my my app again. Also when pressing home in market, again launch app, it shows market page instead of app.
Here is the code which i am using.

```
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
marketIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + AndroidUtils.getPackageName()));
marketIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what did you ask the flags for ?

Comment: I tried by removing flags, but it did not help.

Comment: I used flags because i don't want to keep market activity in stack. It should get cleared when i go back from activity or press home button.

Comment: Ever find a solution, I am having the exact same issue.  New app is stacked on top of mine, and it looks like mine is running the new app, not like it is a new app.

Answer (score 0):

use

Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
marketIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + AndroidUtils.getPackageName()));
startActivity(marketIntent);
don't use the flags because the activities are cleared when u use these flags

Comment: I tried by removing flags, but it did not help. Which activity will be cleared the market activity or my app activity from where i am starting market?